# Why does my PhoneGap page require a reload in order to activate the ajax method?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I'm a veteran programmer but am new to the whole mobile phone app programming and have just delved into PhoneGap. I have a pretty simple page I've put together using JQuery Mobile, PhoneGap, and Jquery but I've run into a snag. When I click on the href to load the "news" page, the .ajax() method doesn't seem to execute. I've got it in the traditional document ready wrapper and removing that doesn't seem to help the issue like I thought. So maybe I'm all screwed up but I cannot figure out why it wont fire UNLESS you refresh the page, then it works fine. Might be an newbie question but I feel like I am first year programmer.

Update: To be clear about what my issue is, I am testing in Firefox and have the PhoneGap desktop app serving the code. When I click on the News button the page loads but the elements that are added by Ajax don't appear. If I hit refresh on the browser, the page reloads and the elements appear. They never show up on the mobile phone unless I make a change to the code which forces the phonegap desktop app to cause the page to reload on the phone. So it's always the reload which causes it to happen.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://code.jquery.com; media-src *; img-src * data:"" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My App</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="news.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">News</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Gigs</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is news.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://code.jquery.com; media-src *; img-src * data:" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var output = $('#news');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/api/news/getnews',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache : false,
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    var story = '<div data-role="collapsible"><h1>'+item.title+'</h1>'
                    + '<p>'+item.body+'<br><small>'
                    + item.date+'</small></p></div>';

                    output.append(story).enhanceWithin();
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });

    });    
</script>
<title>News</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>News</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="news">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <p>Am I collapsible?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone tell me why the ajax wont execute unless I refresh the page first? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using cordova or phonegap please use 'deviceready' instead of jquery ready event both are different. document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false); or $(document).on("deviceready")

Comment: The news page still requires a refresh to get the ajax to start working. So the deviceready didn't help fix my issue.

Comment: worth a try: put your ajax call inside JQM pagecreate event, or if you need refresh at every page visit, inside pageshow : [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)

Comment: @deblocker , no that did not help either.

Comment: It is recommended to load all JS inside `head` of all pages and control them by pagecontainer events as @deblocker has mentioned. If you still don't want to do so, place your JS inside page div.

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out. The news.html page shouldn't have had the html, head section, or body tags.... just simply the contents of the body. After getting rid of that jQuery mobile loaded the new page into the "template" that was already there.

I did go ahead and replace the jquery's document onready event with:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
```

so now my new news.html page looks like this:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

            var output = $('#news');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/api/news/getnews',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache : false,
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, status){
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        var story = '<div data-role="collapsible"><h1>'+item.title+'</h1>'
                        + '<p>'+item.body+'<br><small>'
                        + item.date+'</small></p></div>';

                        output.append(story).enhanceWithin();
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
            });

        });    
    </script>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>News</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="news">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <p>Am I collapsible?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
    </div>
</div>
```

That's the content of the entire page. I will say that after I fixed this I began getting errors with my Content-Security-Policy and that's a whole other question but it seems to be working now and loading the ajax like it is supposed to.

Comment: just a small hint: JQM is managing `div`visibility by looking at `data-role="page"`. So - could be - you will have some trouble with the double `id="home"`. Or look at the docs for `data-rel external`- Check it out.